# Redux preloadedState causing override (and subsequent undefined error) of default reducer state?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I currently am creating a website with react-redux and was getting an error with a typo in the preloadedState variable within createStore. My relevant store code is as follows (Note the `cartitems` spelling in `initialState` instead of `cartItems`):

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
productList: productListReducer,
productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
cart: cartReducer,
})

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

//BELOW GETS PASSED INTO createStore
const initialState = {
    cart: {cartitems: cartItemsFromStorage}
}
```

Within my `cartReducer` the code being affected is as follows:

```
export const cartReducer = (state = {cartItems: []}, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
        const item = action.payload
        const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)
        ***other code below...***
    default:
        return state
}
```

I noticed that this throws an `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.cartItems is undefined` error on the `existItem` line. Why does the addition of the preloadedState cause this issue? From my understanding the reducer's default state (in this case given by `state = {cartItems: []}`) should still be accessible from within the reducer? Is this not the case?

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong. What do you see in the redux-devtools?

Comment: Upon looking at redux-devtools, the `cartitems` (note lowercase 'i', i.e. the same cartitems within the store/preloadedState code) object is shown but not the cartItems from within the reducer itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. From the doc [Initializing State](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/initializing-state#summary):

> Without `combineReducers()` or similar manual code, `preloadedState` always wins over `state = ...` in the reducer because the state passed to the reducer is `preloadedState` and is not `undefined`, so the ES6 argument syntax doesn't apply.

> With `combineReducers()` the behavior is more nuanced. Those reducers whose state is specified in `preloadedState` will receive that state. Other reducers will receive `undefined` and because of that will fall back to the `state = ...` default argument they specify.

For your case, the `preloadedState` is `{cart: { cartitems: cartItemsFromStorage }}`, the `{ cartitems: cartItemsFromStorage }` object will be passed in `cartReducer` as it's default state **rather than the ES6 default argument syntax**.

That's why your cart state shape is `{cartitems: cartItemsFromStorage}`

If the `preloadedState` is `undefined`, then your cart default state is `{cartItems: []}`.

Comment: This makes more sense, I understood the documentation to mean that when `combineReducers()` is NOT used then it will give the `preloadedState` precedence which is where the confusion came in since I did use `combineReducers()` in my store code setup AND it appeared that the `preloadedState` was passed in as default

Comment: @user3491700 Updated answer.